# Create formatted text file from file names using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Edit: I'm new to stack exchange and bash scripting, so please excuse; I'm guessing the reason my question was down-voted was because it was too vague or because I didn't try anything myself first, so I spent the day doing the latter and came up with a way to generate lists of files in the format I need, but I still don't know how to create the necessary structure around it, for example, "MRS_struct = GannetLoad({})"

`ls -1 *GABA.dat | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&'/g" >> filenames.m`

`ls -1 *water.dat | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&'/g" >> filenames.m`

`ls -1 *.nii | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&'/g" >> filenames.m`

/Edit

I have a directory full of 3 series of files:

1. files named `IDv#_GABA.dat` (e.g., `3001v1_GABA.dat`, `3002v1_GABA.dat`)
2. files named `IDv#_water.dat` (e.g., `3001v1_water.dat`, `3002v1_water.dat`)
3. files named `ID_v#.nii` (e.g., `3001_v1.nii`, `3002_v1.nii`).

A given directory would only contain files with one particular *v#* (i.e., only `v1` files or only `v2` files).

I would like to write a text file from these file names in the following format (using the example files above) via a bash script:

```
MRS_struct = GannetLoad({'3001v1_GABA.dat' '3002v1_GABA.dat'},{'3001v1_water.dat' '3002v1_water.dat'});  
MRS_struct = GannetFit(MRS_struct);  
MRS_struct = GannetCoRegister(MRS_struct, {'3001_v1.nii' '3002_v1.nii});  
MRS_struct = GannetSegment(MRS_struct);
```

Comment: Look up shell globbing.

Comment: I noticed that you seem to be missing a closing single-quote mark in the "nii" output line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeing the missing single quote, could you specify where please?

Comment: At the end of `3002_v1.nii`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely an effort in wrapping the correct text around some "printing" loops that act on glob expansions, as Wildcard pointed out in the comments. The one difference (other than a possible single-quote typo in the Q's sample output) is that the below script will put a trailing space after the last element in the list. See the sample output below.

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "MRS_struct = GannetLoad({";
for f in *_GABA.dat
do
  printf "'%s' " "$f"
done
printf "},{"

for f in *_water.dat
do
  printf "'%s' " "$f"
done
printf "});\n"

printf "MRS_struct = GannetFit(MRS_struct);\n"

printf "MRS_struct = GannetCoRegister(MRS_struct, {"
for f in *.nii
do
  printf "'%s' " "$f"
done
printf "});\n"

printf "MRS_struct = GannetSegment(MRS_struct);\n"
```

Sample output from the Question:

```
MRS_struct = GannetLoad({'3001v1_GABA.dat' '3002v1_GABA.dat'},{'3001v1_water.dat' '3002v1_water.dat'});  
MRS_struct = GannetFit(MRS_struct);  
MRS_struct = GannetCoRegister(MRS_struct, {'3001_v1.nii' '3002_v1.nii});  
MRS_struct = GannetSegment(MRS_struct);
```

Output from the above script:

```
MRS_struct = GannetLoad({'3001v1_GABA.dat' '3002v1_GABA.dat' },{'3001v1_water.dat' '3002v1_water.dat' });
MRS_struct = GannetFit(MRS_struct);
MRS_struct = GannetCoRegister(MRS_struct, {'3001_v1.nii' '3002_v1.nii' });
MRS_struct = GannetSegment(MRS_struct);
```

Comment: I can't try this until tomorrow, but this looks great! I'll update success tomorrow.